# UWP doesn't end debugging when app is closed, when the event handler is async

Tags: .net, uwp

Why isn't my UWP application exit debugging mode when the application is closed by user when clicking X on top right?

It exits normally when there is no async event on the control, but once I changed the button's click event to be async (need this for FilePicker) the app just don't exit debugging mode.

Seems like something is holding reference on something, but how do I debug this? And why does this happens only when there is async operation?

The codes:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void OnButtonPickSingleFileAsyncClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.List;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;

        var pickedFile = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (pickedFile != null)
        {
            filePath.Text = pickedFile.Path;
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestRepro.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestRepro"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Pick File Async" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="OnButtonPickSingleFileAsyncClicked"/>
        <TextBlock Name="filePath" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: In general, when I close the UWP app, the visual studio debugging will stop automatically. But your question was strange. Sometimes I meet this problem because of insufficient memory. I'm not sure if it's the same issue with yours. If you're using visual studio 2017, please first check the [Visual Studio 2017 System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs#visual-studio-2017-system-requirements)

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I'm pretty sure I met the requirements. Win10 Enterprise Build 17134, i7-7820HQ, 8GB RAM. I'm on VS2017 15.7.0, UWP target version Win10 Build 17134. This whole PC is running on Windows hosted on VMWare Fusion. Any idea?

Comment: what if you change the method type from `void` to `Task`?

Comment: @kurakura88 I got an error CS0407 "blablabla has the wrong return type". Besides, I thought it is considered acceptable to use async void for event handlers?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see it properly, you are writing the event handler in code-behind, so... I guess, I don't think you can even change it to async. It is different story if you are binding that event handler to a ICommand (that calls async method) in the VM.

Comment: @Farid I could now reproduce your issue. But sometime it will exit after several seconds. It seems a visual studio issue. You could see this thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/245946/multiple-processes-have-been-debugged.html I suggest that you'd better report this issue to visual studio developer community forum.